# Words in a string return unexpected value

Tags: python, string

Why does my boolean return `True` when I expect `False`?

String `a` is "7582 +   group by 1,2; ERROR: File ACT2EST.SUMMARY_CFS.DATA does not exist."

My code expression is `"WARNING" and "ERROR" in a`; this evaluates to `True`.

I apply the same code, `"WARNING" and "ERROR" in b`, to another string `b = "if abc ; WARNING: message. ERROR Message."`, and my output is `True` as expected.

Can someone let me know what is wrong with my code and why when running it with string a my output is True instead of False? Btw, I use python 2.7

Comment: It's blowing my mind I can't find a dupe target for this. This is a really common logic issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because you did *not* check to see whether "WARNING" is in the string; all you checked was the truth value of the string.  You need

```
"WARNING" in a and "ERROR" in a
```

Logical operators do *not* distribute over their objects the way they can in English.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy, you could do:

```
a = "This is a demo text"

if any( x in a for x in ["This", "rocks", "scissors"] ):
    print("Text contains any of This, rocks, scissors")
else:
    print("Text has neither of This, rocks, scissors")


if all( x in a for x in ["This", "rocks", "scissors"] ):
    print("Text contains all of This, rocks, scissors")
else:
    print("Not all in!")
```

`any` and `all` are built-ins:

- https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#any
- https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#all

that operate on iterables and check if any/all in the iterable are `True`

For only 2 values simply chaining `if "this" in a and "that" in a:` is ok though